# python recursively rename directories

Tags: python, operating-system, listdir

I made a script to rename directories with a name that contains spaces or special characters recursively:

```
import os
import re
import pdb

def renameInvalid(root):
    print("root is: " + root)
    for f in os.listdir(root):        
        if os.path.isdir(f):            
            old = f
            f = f.replace(" ", "_")
            f = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]', '',f)
            if old != f:
                print(root + " na substitutie")
                os.rename(old,f)
                print(root + " na hernoemen")
                print("renamed " + old + " to " + f )
                #pdb.set_trace() 
                f = '/' + f
                pad = root + f                
                renameInvalid(str(pad))

mountpunt = os.getcwd()
renameInvalid(mountpunt)
```

You can test this script by making two directories with names containing spaces. You place one of the directories inside the other and run the script from inside the first directory. The script renames the first directory but generates an OSError on isdir(f).
Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Regards,

Comment: I would not suggest running an untested script that changes people's file system on their local machines. You need a sandbox of some kind (such as a virtual machine) to test stuff like this.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer (thanks to timbaileyjones for his solution).

```
import os
import re

def renameInvalid(root):    
    for f in os.listdir(root):        
        old = f
        f = f.replace(" ", "_")
        f = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]', '',f)
        if old != f:                              
                os.rename(old,f)                
                print("renamed " + old + " to " + f )
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            os.chdir(f)
            renameInvalid(".")
            os.chdir("..")            

renameInvalid(".")
```

One should only run this code if they know what they are doing. It renames all the folders and files with whitespace or special characters in the filename.

Regards,

Comment: I forgot to say that the dot stands for the current directory and the double dot is the parent directory

Comment: Also put a dot in the regex (after the underscore), otherwise the dot separating the file extension disappears.